# How to continue using the value returned from getOrPut Map in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

I am new to Kotlin and come from a JS background. I am trying to map through a list and perform some operations on them and return a list.

```kotlin
val rowValue=readHeader.map { header-> row.getOrPut(header) { "" } }
```

I am trying to do further operations on the value returned by this code block.

```
row.getOrPut(header) { "" }
```

So, I am trying to do this:

```kotlin
       val rowValue=readHeader.map { header-> { val rowVal = row.getOrPut(header) { "" }
                if (rowVal.contains(","))
                {
                    "\""+"$rowVal"+"\""
                }
                else{
                    rowVal
                }
            } }
```

The result is like so.

```kotlin
() -> kotlin.String!,() -> kotlin.String!
```

I am trying to loop through `rowHeader` which is a `list of string` and get the `rowVal` which is a map of key, value. And then check if the value is like `apple,mango` return `\"apple,mango\"` or return `banana` for all other case. How do I do that?

So, basically I am trying to use the value that I get in
`val rowVal = row.getOrPut(header) { "" }` for further operations: eg: `rowVal+1`.

I have done this using `forEach` loop. How do I do this using a `.map` since the map returns a list?

```js
        val rowData= emptyList<String>().toMutableList()
            readHeader.forEach { header->
                val value = row.getOrPut(header) { "" }
                if (value.contains(",") || value.contains(" ")){
                    rowData.add("\"${value}\"")
                }
                else{
                    rowData.add(value)
                }
            }
```

Expected input i,e

```kotlin
row =mapOf("firstName" to "John", "lastName" to "Doe", "fruits" to "apple,mango", "column" to "Value")
row1 =mapOf("firstName" to "Jane", "lastName" to "", "fruits" to "banana,grapes", "column" to "Value")
```

Expected output:

```
John,Doe,"apple,mango",Value
Jane,,"banana,grapes",Value
```

Comment: Can you clarify, what type is `readHeader`, and what type is `row`? It seems `row` is a map of header keys (which `readHeader` is a list of) to String values. And it's unclear what your end result is supposed to be.

Comment: `rowheader` is a list of strings and `row` is a map<K,V>.

Comment: What I'm saying is, I can't understand what you're trying to do from your description. We don't just need the types, but what exactly you are trying to do to each of the objects that you have. What end result, and what side effects along the way.

Comment: Hope it gives some clarity.

Comment: We now know the expected output, what is the input, and the input format? BR

Comment: I would highly recommend using a proper CSV writer library instead of trying to do your own escaping of columns that contain commas. You've missed out a lot of other things beside checking for comma. What if it contains a quotation mark? You'll need to escape it. What if it contains a newline? You'll need to read two lines, join them together, and escape it. What if... there are countless possibilities. Don't do it. Use a CSV writer library.

Comment: @PrabhakarMaity Thanks for updating your question with test-data. I updated my answer accordingly. BR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updated answer after OP added test-input in question.

The below code with tests should answer your question. Code is written inside a Kotest.

```
import io.kotest.core.spec.style.BehaviorSpec
import io.kotest.data.forAll
import io.kotest.data.row
import io.kotest.matchers.shouldBe

class MyTest() : BehaviorSpec({

    given("StackOverflow question") {

        forAll(
            row(
                mapOf("firstName" to "John", "lastName" to "Doe", "fruits" to "apple,mango", "column" to "Value"),
                listOf("John", "Doe", "\"apple,mango\"", "Value")
            ),
            row(
                mapOf("firstName" to "Jane", "lastName" to "", "fruits" to "banana,grapes", "column" to "Value"),
                listOf("Jane", "", "\"banana,grapes\"", "Value")
            )
        ) { input, expectedResult ->

            `when`("mapping items $input, $expectedResult") {

                val result = input.values.map {
                    if (it.contains(",") || it.contains(" ")) {
                        "\"${it}\""
                    } else {
                        it
                    }
                }

                then("result should be as expected") {
                    result shouldBe expectedResult
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```